# What's the git equivalent to p4's "..." pattern?

Tags: git

When I used p4 (Perforce) I would often use the "..." pattern, which is sort of like "*" except it traverses levels of the file system hierarchy (ie: it also matches slashes). This was handy for dealing with source files that were several levels down the directory tree.

For example:

```
p4 diff foo/.../*.py
```

This would "p4 diff" all of the Python files under the subtree "foo".

Is there an easy way to get the same result with git? Right now I have to do something like this:

```
git diff $(find foo -name '*.py')
```

which isn't nearly as convenient.

Comment: Great question, I have wanted to do this myself and not found a way either. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git generally relies on the pathname expansion capabilities provided by the shell - and rightfully so, since pathname expansion is not exactly the job of a version control system. So you should be looking at your shell of choice to see if it supports something like the `...` pathname expansion. If you're using bash, you can set the `globstar` option

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and then you can use a double asterisk to get the expansion you want:

```
git diff foo/**/*.py
```

Note that, based on my tests, the double asterisk doesn't seem to match partial pathname components. In other words, it has to be followed by and preceded by a slash for that pattern to match something like `foo/bar/blah/baz.py`. If you try writing `foo/ba**/*.py` it will match the same thing as `foo/ba*/*.py`.

Comment: Are you sure that the user here doesn't just want foo/*/*.py? Also, what is the difference here?

Comment: Normally I'd agree that "pathname expansion is not exactly the job of [anything other than the shell]", but I think version control systems are a special case as you frequently need to refer to files that aren't actually mapped onto the real file system when using a VCS. This is less true in git than it is in p4, because git doesn't let you map only a portion of the repository to your workspace, but it still happens. For example, if I git rm a file, the shell won't see that file anymore, and so using `git diff [pattern]` will never match it.

Comment: That said, I didn't know about globstar, so +1 for at least getting me ~80% of what I want. :-)

Comment: Ah, so you want to find deleted files and old version too? I couldn't tell that from your question. That's going to be a little harder. But I think git may do some wildcard parsing in certain contexts, so it might be possible. Someone with more git expertise than me is going to have to handle that one. In the meantime, I'd start by looking at `git help diff-tree`.

Comment: Yeah, deleted and old (or even from other branches) versions of files would be nice, when appropriate, though stuff in the workspace is probably at least 80% of what I want. That `**` looks different from `...` should be enough to remind me of the different semantics in those cases where I care. Aside: globstar appears to be a bash 4.x thing. For Mac users reading this: get bash from MacPorts. (Snow Leopard has 3.2.48 by default -- not sure what Lion has.)